# Firebase Auth identify if the user entered the wrong password

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am currently using Firebase password authentication and this is my login method its very common.

I have an `else` block statement that tells the user that the login is not successful but that doesn't tell the user what specifically is wrong. How can I identify if the user entered the wrong password?

```
private void signIn(String email, String password, final View view) {
    Log.d(TAG, "signIn:" + email);
    if (!validateForm()) {
        return;
    }
    showProgress();
    // [START sign_in_with_email]
    fLogInAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        FirebaseUser currUser = fLogInAuth.getCurrentUser();
                        establishUI(currUser);
                    } else {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        establishUI(null);
                        Snackbar.make(view, "Unable to login, Please try again in a few moments",Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                }
            });
}
```

Comment: It's bad for the security of an application to indicate what's wrong with a login.  That tells a hacker how to try more effectively to break into an account.  It's better to be vague about the problem.

Comment: @DougStevenson I thought about that, I just wanted to show a small TextView whenever the user wants to reset his/her password. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Use `task.getException().getLocalizedMessage()` inside `onComplete()` to get error message.